# Debugging how symbolic link is getting broken in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, symbolic-link, auditd

I have a symbolic link of the form

```
ubuntu@platform1:~$ ls -lrt
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar  2 15:02 deploy
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 May 25 18:27 logs -> /var/log/arkin
```

Disk layout

```
ubuntu@platform1:~$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-var            853G  3.7G  806G   1% /var
/dev/mapper/vg-var+log         49G  1.1G   45G   3% /var/log
/dev/mapper/vg-var+log+audit   20G   60M   19G   1% /var/log/audit
/dev/mapper/vg-home            30G  6.5G   22G  24% /home
```

But many times I am observing that symbolic link is changed to

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May 31 08:41 logs
```

Can someone let me know if there is a way to enable audit logs on the folder `/home/ubuntu/logs` so that I can get some idea which operation is breaking the symbolic link and creating a new `/home/ubuntu/logs` or some other ways I can debug this problem?

- Filesystem - ext4
- OS - Ubuntu 16.04

**EDIT**

I followed the steps as suggested in the answer. I had the following symbolic link :-

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 Jun  3 07:26 logs -> /var/log/arkin`

Added the below rule in `/etc/audit/audit.rules`

`-a always,exit -F dir=/home/ubuntu/logs -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat  -S rmdir -k log_link`

Then restarted audit service

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~$ sudo service auditd stop
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~$ sudo service auditd start
```

Executed the below command

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~$ sudo ln -svf /var/log/arkin /home/ubuntu/logs
'/home/ubuntu/logs/arkin' -> '/var/log/arkin'
```

But I am not seeing any audit entry

`# aureport -k -i | grep log_link`

Comment: The obvious suspect is whatever program is writing logs to that location.

Comment: Every process writes its logs in a sub-directory under that directory. There are quite a few process accessing this directory. So it is getting difficult to identify the culprit.

Comment: I think you should try `audit` or `aide`, to debug more.

Comment: For auditd you can try below

`$ tail -2 /etc/audit/audit.rules 
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat  -S rmdir -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat  -S rmdir -k delete`

Comment: Yes I am looking for audit / aide only. But I am not able to find how to add a rule for which will log an entry when the symblink `/home/ubuntu/logs` is deleted or the `/home/ubuntu/logs` is created.

Comment: @asktyagi - Can you post your comment as an answer with little more explanation about the command?

Answer (score 1):

For auditd you can try below

```
$tail -2 /etc/audit/audit.rules 
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat  -S rmdir -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat  -S rmdir -k delete
```

Here you can specify directory too

```
-F dir=<directory or mount point>
```

Here is the used options description in shot for more details please check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditctl.8.html

```
 -a [list,action|action,list] 
 -S [Syscall name or number|all]
 -k key Set a filter key on an audit rule.
```

Some more examples for different rules are:

```
## Audit log access
-a always,exit -F dir=/var/log/audit/ -F perm=r -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -F key=access-audit-trail
## Attempts to Alter Process and Session Initiation Information
-a always,exit -F path=/var/run/utmp -F perm=wa -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -F key=session
-a always,exit -F path=/var/log/btmp -F perm=wa -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -F key=session
-a always,exit -F path=/var/log/wtmp -F perm=wa -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -F key=session
```

Comment: I followed the steps you suggested but this does not seem to be creating any audit entry. Check my edit in the question.